# ElasticSearch: Can I have some (subset of all) fields "frozen == indexed on demand" in one index?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have documents of the following type and many indices (hundreds) like that per day (Ts of data per day):

```
{
  "date_time":"07/May/2019:02:37:19  +0000",
  "ip":"17.15.15.15", 
  "status":"200",
  "request_url":"https://my.domain.com/some/long/path/to/page",
  "response_time": "0.01"
}
```

The first 3 fields (date_time, ip, status) will be searched by/ aggregated by a lot, a few times per second/min.

The last two fields (request_url, response_time) will be searched by very infrequently - once a month or even a few months - but they will be searched by.

What would be the most efficient mapping for these requirements?
Obviously, the first 3 fields have to be fully indexed, as doc_type.

What about the last 2 , infrequently searched ones? If I totally disable indexing for them - set "enabled" = FALSE (I'd have to move them into a separate object as AFAIK single fields can't be disabled, only objects ) - then I will never be able to search them, unless I search the _source content. Given the volume of data I have (Ts of data, hundreds of indices, per day) - it is going to kill my cluster :)

I'm almost looking for an option like the "frozen" indices - for which indexing structures are loaded into memory on demand. But, I need this on a field-level, not the whole index level. So that only a subset of fields would be "indexed on demand"

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Marina